# Wikipedia database: categories and category mapping across languages

Tags: wikipedia

I've imported the wikipedia database in four languages with the goal of running some machine learning algorithms on it for text classification. The import doesn't populate the "category" table though. Am I missing something?

I would also like to know if there was a way to map categories across the different language databases? i.e. know which category in English represents which category in German for example?

Thanks!

Comment: It turns out I imported the articles only (using mwdumper). The categories (as well as the pages) and other table dumps can be downloaded here: https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/. "en" can be replaced with the desired language code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second question, the answer is in the langlinks table (categories have page_id just like pages). Se more here: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Langlinks_table

Comment: Anyway beware that structure of categories is different in different Wikipedias and this makes mapping categories between Wikipedias harder than mapping articles.